# Keycloak user store provider above 18.0.0

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I want to update my Keycloak to latest version which is currently 21.0.0. But I saw that we don't have UserStorageProvider.class within 'services' package, now it's within 'legacy'. What is the new approach to custom users identity provider so I can avoid to use legacy package?

Comment: Have you looked at the Keycloak documentation about upgrading? https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/#intro

Comment: Yes It will be some new storage api in Keycloak:
https://www.keycloak.org/2022/07/storage-map.html
But is recommended version is =>20